# Unable to see log output of Spring when starting Jetty from Maven plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, logging, spring-mvc, jetty

I am developing a webapp in Eclipse Juno as a Maven multi-module project using Spring MVC and the Jetty Maven plugin version 8.1.7.v20120910 with HSQL as in-memory DB during development. I want to start Jetty from within the IDE using the jetty:run goal. The problem is that I cannot see any log outputs from Spring, but I suspect the context is indeed being loaded since console log outputs stop briefly - just as long as it would take to load my yet so small Spring context - before throwing an NPE on an Autowired bean. So my suspicion is that something went wrong while starting up the Spring context.

This is the log output just before it "stops" briefly:

```
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = F:\projects\matching\template\template-app\src\main\webapp
2013-01-26 11:09:18.130:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.7.v20120910
2013-01-26 11:09:20.704:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
```

Which after the pause is followed by:

```
2013-01-26 11:09:35.884:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2013-01-26 11:09:36.742:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/},file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/
2013-01-26 11:09:36.742:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/},file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/
2013-01-26 11:09:36.742:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/},file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/
2013-01-26 11:09:36.743:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/},file:/F:/projects/matching/template/template-app/src/main/webapp/
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now I am confident that I will be able to fix whatever is causing the NPE, but for that I need to see what is happening to my Spring context. I used to work on the same constellation of tools last year, when a colleague had set it up with what I believe was the same configuration as I am using now.

I have searched the web all morning and couldn't find anything useful about it, only the vague suggestion to run Jetty externally and assemble the war and deploy the app, which is exactly not what I want.

This is my pom's build configuration:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <warName>template</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <webApp>
                        <jettyEnvXml>${jettyEnvXml-file}</jettyEnvXml>
                    </webApp>
                    <contextPath>template</contextPath>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                            <value>file:jetty/log4j-jetty.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And this is my log4j configuration for Jetty:

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.threshold=ALL

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleLogger

log4j.appender.consoleLogger=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%t]: %m%n
log4j.appender.consoleLogger.Threshold=TRACE
```

Could it have to do with this line at the beginning of my log?

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

But as far as I know it's just an m2e bug that can be ignored. I have slf4j in my classpath though.

When I run my unit tests with HSQL in the SpringJPA module, it works nicely, so I suspect it's a Jetty issue or something with my log4j configuration is just bogus.

Any ideas, hints, helps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have slf4j in your classpath, then Jetty will use slf4j.

Make sure you [setup/configure for slf4j](http://slf4j.org/manual.html).

You can even [setup slf4j to have its log events route to log4j](http://slf4j.org/legacy.html) for actual writing to disk or presenting to your console.